# SEO - Friendly URL redirect is not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

On my test server with Apache and php7.1 I can work with an URL like `example.com/news/id/title`
and it redirects me to
`example.com/news.php`
but the url is still the same and I can use the Parameters after the slashes.

Now I work on a live hosting and its not working anymore.
I tried to redirect with htaccess and it works for
`example.com/news` to redirect to `example.com/news.php`
but if I put anything after that i get an 404 error.

How can I redirect the requests from
`/news/id/` to `news.php` where I want to read out the id?
And why did that work natively on my test server?

Thousand thanks for any hint.

My actual `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^news/(.*) /news.php/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Can you share more details?

Comment: Note sure why this question was closed? All the details are there in the question if you have experience with MultiViews and `.htaccess`.

Comment: I don't know it either. I did all the improvements in the thread. 
@MrWhite thanks a lot for your help and time!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you may have a conflict with MultiViews (part of mod_negotiation). You need to make sure MultiViews is disabled at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

If MultiViews is enabled and you make a request for `/news/id/` then mod_negotiation makes an internal subrequest for `/news.php` (without any additional path-info) before mod_rewrite is able to rewrite the request.

> why did that work natively on my testserver?

MultiViews is disabled by default on Apache, however, a number of shared web hosts do enable it for some reason. It makes extensionless URLs "magically" work without doing anything, however, this potentially creates *duplicate content* (bad for SEO) and causes no end of unexpected conflicts with mod_rewrite, such as this.

**UPDATE:** Change your directives to something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^news/(.*) /news.php/$1 [L]
```

This *internally rewrites* (as opposed to `_externally redirects_) all requests that start` /news/`to`/news.php/`- where``is passed as _path-info_ to`/news.php`. (I assume that passing the URL-path as path-info is the intention? You could instead use the query string or not pass anything in the directive and simply examine the requested URL in PHP? - but this might require marginally more processing in PHP.)

There's no need to check that the target file exists, since it's hardcoded in this example.

Removal of the `R` flag results in the *internal rewrite*.

You will need to clear your browser cache since the 301 (permanent) redirect will have been cached by the browser.

If you need a more generic solution that rewrites `/<action>/<data>` to `/<action>.php/<data>` then write it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*) /$1.php/$1 [L]
```

Again, no need to check that the request does not map to a file before checking that it does map to a file when `.php` is appended.

Note that this is not using a *TestString* of the form `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` (as you had initially), as this can result in a rewrite loop (500 error) for certain requests. See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/989351/49157) to the following question on ServerFault that explains this further: https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems like thats the point on my test server. But how can I redirect all requests from `example.com/news/id/title` to `example.com/news.php?=id` on my live server? I found a solution to redirect all requests to index.php but I want to work with different php files.

Comment: I'd overlooked that you were _externally redirecting_ the request. It looks like you should be _internally rewriting_ the request instead. I've updated my answer.

Comment: ++ indeed `MultiViews` can be very annoying sometimes

Comment: @CodeTube How did you get on with this? If this answered your question then please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the tick/checkmark next to the answer (to help other readers and to remove the question from the unanswered question queue). Once you have 15 rep you can also upvote answers that you find helpful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)